# Error while downloading .xlsm excel sheet through a popup window

Tags: popupwindow, xlsm

We have to provide a download option to an .xlsm (macros enabled) excel sheet by creating the popup window. While downloading the excel sheet, it is throwing the below error.

> Excel cannot open the file "null.xlsm" because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file

In the code we are providing a link in a plugin & passing 2 parameters to that link. After clicking it invokes a JSP file which will in turn invoke a java class file & passes those 2 parameters. We are inserting the data into macros excel sheet in the Java class file and we are calling that class file through the JSP Page.

The JSP code in the body is as follows:

```
<%
    String projectName = request.getParameter("ProjectName");
    String fixVersion= request.getParameter("FixVersion");
    FinalExtraction fe = new FinalExtraction();
    fe.getIssuesFromProject(projectName,fixVersion);
%>
```